# How to Make Button on Tkinter That Will Wait for Keyboard Input and When given Will Change a Variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For example:

Press button -> User Press C on their Keyboard -> A variable changes to the letter C -> Button no longer waits for input

Sorry if this is super easy to do. I have no experience with tkinter and have tried to achieve this and do research on it but all my methods just makes the window freeze or not output anything at all.

Comment: GUI programs don't wait for input. Tkinter `Button` widget don't respond to keyboard input. Probably the closest thing you could do it make one that would call a function _when it was pressed_ by clicking on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Button no longer waits for input" ?

Comment: I'm somewhat aware of that from when I was watching tkinter tutorials. I tried using 'pynput' but that also didn't work (just froze). Are there any modules you are aware of, martineau, that will allow me to have a function that can be called by tkinter that will allow for it to wait for keyboard input?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? The wording and question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, width=200, height=200)

        self.key = ''
        self.key_detection = False

        self.detect_button = Button(master, text="Detect", command=self.button_click)
        self.detect_button.pack()

        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.key_event)

    def key_event(self, event):
        if self.key_detection:
            self.key = event.char
            print self.key
            self.key_detection = not self.key_detection

    def button_click(self):
        self.key_detection = not self.key_detection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui_frame = GUI()
    gui_frame.mainloop()
```

When you click the Detect button and then press a key, the value of the key will be stored in the variable `self.key`, then it will be printed to the console, and the key detection will be switched off, until you press the Detect button again.

With the Detect button you can switch on and off the key detection.

Hope it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for. <3